# What does にして mean in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, translation

Tell me please what is にして means in the following sentence and how can we translate 「傲慢にして古き蛇」 part?

> 我が罪の名は[傲慢]{ごうまん}**にして**古き蛇。[刮目]{かつもく}して見るがいい。

Thank you.

Comment: Do you have an idea of how this sentence might translate? ^^

Comment: Probably meaning #1 of http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/jn2/166889/m0u/

Comment: @Chocolate:  There are three different lines on that page marked with a `1`.  どれですか？

Comment: @istrasci えとね、一番上の、黒で、中抜きの、四角いやつです。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`The name of our sin is Pride, the olden snake. Be wary!`

Chocolate's link should be it. にして sounds more elaborate than a mundane という.

Comment: `傲慢にして古き蛇` = `傲慢という古い蛇` （傲慢＝古い蛇） ってことですよね？ ［傲慢にして古き］蛇 → ［傲慢であって古い］蛇 ＝ "an arrogant old snake" ってことはないんでしょうか・・・？